# Zend framework - insert less than 500 rows only

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, insert

I'm using Zend framework with Mysql. My application loads the data from a csv file into the mysql database. The table has two columns (`id` and `name`). The application uses `file_get_contents` to read the csv file and uses  $this->insert($data) of Zend_Db_Table. The file has exactly two columns similar to the table.

The problem I'm facing is, while inserting data, it inserts around 500 rows only. Remaining rows are not inserted in database. No errors are shown in the browser and the application works like nothing happened. I tried with different data but the problem is the same.

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$i=1;
for($c=1; $c < (count($lines)-1); $c++) {
list($field1, $field2) = explode(",", $lines[$i]);
$borrower= new Application_Model_DbTable_TempB();
$borrower->uploadborrower($field1, $field2); 
$i++;
```

The uploadborrower function simply makes array $data and insert by using `this->insert($data)` – A

Can anyone help me to find where the problem is and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Some source code would help :)

Comment: $file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        $lines = explode("\n", $file); //
          $i=1;                    
          for($c=1; $c < (count($lines)-1); $c++) {
          list($field1, $field2) = explode(",", $lines[$i]);
          $borrower= new Application_Model_DbTable_TempB();
          $borrower->uploadborrower($field1, $field2);
                    $i++;                                                  The uploadborrower function simply makes array $data and insert by using this->insert($data)

Comment: i m sure problem is with insert only. There is no problem while i read the file and display in the browser only.

Comment: For a one time import you can use the import function of phpmyadmin or some other Mysql frontend. If this is a common function of your application the timeout may be a very good place to start. You may need to extend the timeout of php operations (this is typically 30 seconds) or you may want to break the input down into smaller chunks.

Comment: Just for clarity, if php's execution time is exceeded, won't it throw a Fatal Error. Something like "Maximum execution time of X seconds have been exceeded."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
set_time_limit(0);
$i=1;
for($c=1; $c < (count($lines)-1); $c++) {
list($field1, $field2) = explode(",", $lines[$i]);
$borrower= new Application_Model_DbTable_TempB();
$borrower->uploadborrower($field1, $field2); 
$i++;
```

Comment: I would suggest to move set_time_limit(0) at the beginning of the code. Usually you shouldn't have any problems for files in local file system, but if the CSV file is really massive and it's loaded from a remote URL, it could take a lot and you could have timeout problem again.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be a problem of timeout? If the CSV is massive, it can happen.

Try:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

before to execute your code.